# jQuery dialog - div positioned on top of dialog box inputs disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The problem is this:

A dialog box is opened. I click the input field of the dialog box to open a div that is absolutely positioned over the dialog box. The input cannot be interacted with.

Here is the example on [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aY9ms/3/)

You can mouse over the input and the mouse cursor will change to the 'I' icon. You can even interact with the close anchor tag on the absolutely positioned div. It's not a z-index issue. It works in jQuery UI 1.9 and older. Strangely, after the absolute div has been added to the DOM, if you append an empty div to the end of the body html (using firebug to edit the code realtime), the input works.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Bontke

```
$('#open_dialog').click(function (event) {

var dialog_html = '<div id="dialog_body">' + 
                      '<input type="text" name="test1"/>' +
                  '</div>';

$(dialog_html).dialog({
    title: 'WTF Test',
    height: 110,
    width: 300,
    modal: 'true',
    close: function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $('#test_div').remove();
    }
});

//dialog input click
$('input[name=test1]').click(function (event) {
    var html = $('<div id="test_div" style="border: 1px solid red; z-index: 10000; position: absolute; left: 45%; top: 60%; width: 235px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;"><input name="foobar"/><a id="test_close" style="color: white;" href="#">close</a><br/><span style="color: white">super awesome text</span></div>'),
        body = $(document.body);

        if ($('#test_div').length === 0) {
            //append div to body
            html.appendTo(body);
            //add close functionality to test_div
            $('#test_close').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //remove test_div from DOM
                $(event.currentTarget).parent().remove();
            });
        }
});
});
```

Comment: I don't have any solutions, but in testing your fiddle I was able to confirm your findings, and got a few more data points.  I set the input to a checkbox, and it was able to handle the click event well enough.  Even using the chrome debugger to set the state of the textbox to :focus, it didn't get focus, so the issue seems specific to keyboard focus, but that's all I have.

Answer (score 1):

The `dialog_html` dialog is set to `modal: 'true'` which means it will deactivate everything else on the page. If you remove this it removes any problems. I think you're getting mixed results because you're adding to the DOM after jQuery has made the dialog modal and you really shouldn't be able to interact with the second popup at all, but it is breaking. You may want to try making the second pop-up modal, or adding it as a child of the first dialog rather than appending it to `document.body`

Comment: Unfortunately, setting modal to false in the jsfiddle doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Setting modal to false doesn't change anything, but removing the entire line does.

Comment: Just noticed it's because there's single quotes around the boolean which means the 'false' wouldn't have been working properly. Makes a change without them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed reply, here is the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/aY9ms/5/

I want the dialog box to be a modal. You are right, the adding the DOM is the because of how dialog box works. And in my case, it is better to add any html to the dialog box parent for better memory clean up. And adjusting the overflow on the dialog box allows the div to float over the dialog box as I want.

Thanks for all of the feedback and help!

```
var $ = $j;
var dialog_html = '<div id="dialog_body">' + 
                      '<input type="text" name="test1"/>' +
                  '</div>';

$(dialog_html).dialog({
    title: 'WTF Test',
    height: 110,
    dragable: true,
    width: 300,
    modal: 'true',
    close: function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $('#test_div').remove();
    }
});

//dialog input click
$('input[name=test1]').click(function (event) {
    var html = $('<div id="test_div" style="border: 1px solid red; z-index: 10000; position: absolute; left: 45%; top: 60%; width: 235px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;"><input name="foobar"/><a id="test_close" style="color: white;" href="#">close</a><br/><span style="color: white">super awesome text</span></div>'),
        dialog_box = $('#dialog_body').parent(),
        body = $(document.body);

        //adjust css
        dialog_box.css({'overflow': 'inherit'});

        if ($('#test_div').length === 0) {
            //append div to body
            //html.appendTo(body);
            html.appendTo(dialog_box);
            //add close functionality to test_div
            $('#test_close').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //remove test_div from DOM
                $(event.currentTarget).parent().remove();
            });
        }
});
```